# Making a function to build a particular set of combinations

Tags: julia, combinatorics

I'm trying to make a function `f` such that

```
f(1) == ((1,),)
f(2) == ((1,), (2,), (1,2))
f(3) == ((1,), (2,), (3,), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2,3))
f(4) == ((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,4), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4))
```

and so on. Anyone have any clever ideas on how to generate this programmatically? I'm sure there's some fancy name for this operation but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combinatorics package has this:

```
using Combinatorics

combinations(1:n) # iterator of all combinations
```

For example

```
julia> collect(combinations(1:3))
7-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]      
 [2]      
 [3]      
 [1, 2]   
 [1, 3]   
 [2, 3]   
 [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that combinations is an iterator, you can use it in a for loop

```
for c in combinations(1:n)
    ...
end
```

without creating all combinations in memory at once (you only create them if you `collect` the iterator). `combinations` returns a `Vector` instead of a tuple so that the type of `c` does not change from iteration to iteration.

There is some additional information at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/generate-all-subsets-of-a-set/12810/10.

Answer (score 1):

Two answers which were suggested to me on the julialang slack:

```
using Combinatorics

f(n) = unique(sort.(vcat([collect(permutations(1:n, i)) for i in 1:n]...)))
```

```
jointuple(x,y) = (x...,y...)
function f(x) 
    if x == 0
        []
    elseif x == 1
        [(1,);]
    else 
        a = f(x-1) 
        vcat(a,(x,),map(z->jointuple(z,x),a)) 
    end 
end
```